# How do I Count all the checkboxes once I hit the select all Button

Tags: jquery

I have a select all button that helps me select all checkboxes, It works fine, I get the total count of checked items, then if I select the checkboxes one after the other, I also get the count, but the issue is that when I select all after I have selected some, the count goes to 0 again.

```
this.countRecipients = function() {
  $('.recipients').click(function() {

    if ($(this).attr('data-count')) {
      $(this).removeAttr('data-count');
    } else {
      $(this).attr('data-count', 1);
    }

    $('.value').html(self.countSelectedRecipies());

  });

  $('#checkAll').click(function() {

    if ($('.recipients').attr('data-count')) {
      $('.recipients').removeAttr('data-count');
      self.countSelectedRecipies();
    } else {
      $('.recipients').attr('data-count', 1);
      self.countSelectedRecipies();
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Can you update your question with HTML markup so that it will be helpful to reproduce the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably wanted to loop over those elements, like this:

```
  $('#checkAll').click(function() {
    $('.recipients').each(function() {
      if ($(this).attr('data-count')) {
        $(this).removeAttr('data-count');
      } else {
        $(this).attr('data-count', 1);
      }
    });

    self.countSelectedRecipies();
  });
```

Also, I'd require to check if checkbox is checked using `$(this).is(':checked')` instead of relying on data attribute in your first event handler...